# Are these macros equivalent?

Tags: rust, macros

```
macro_rules! force_client_run {
    ($cx:expr, $func:expr $(, $arg:expr)* ) => {
        foo($cx, move |_| { $func($($arg,)*); });
    };
}
```

and

```
macro_rules! force_client_run {
    ($cx:expr, $func:expr $(, $arg:expr)* ) => {
        foo($cx, move |_| { $func($($arg),*); });
    };
}
```

The difference is the placing of the comma: `$func($($arg,)*` `$func($($arg),*`

is one preferred over the other?

I ran both using `cargo expand --ugly` and they're both the same, neither has a trailing comma.

But it seems like they should have a trailing comma because the comma is part of the matching group, no? Is there some magic occurring I'm not aware of?

Comment: [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=7608aa81ed11452a44366b0f04081e30) (I thought they're not equal and I could easily find a counterexample. Zilch.)

Comment: @Caesar there is a difference if the macro adds an extra parameter to the function call after those supplied by the user: [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=94bb473a1335fb1f9eacaad710d4c5ee).

Comment: Note that they _still_ appear to expand to the same code, but the one with `$(…),*` fails to compile and the error message complains about a missing coma in contradiction with the expanded code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$(),*` means to put `,` in between each repetition, so no trailing comma. `$(,)*` is not special: it just repeats the inner part and therefore has a trailing comma.

I'm not sure why the trailing comma disappears. Trailing commas in function arguments are optional anyway so it doesn't really matter. However, you can see that the macros do differ when you add in another argument:

```rs
$func($($arg,)* 6);
$func($($arg),*, 6);
```

Those are both valid, while

```rs
$func($($arg),* 6);
$func($($arg,)*, 6);
```

are not.

There isn't much for style guidelines for macros. The [macro API guidelines](https://rust-lang.github.io/api-guidelines/macros.html) are only concerned with the outer interface, and rustfmt does basically nothing inside `macro_rules!`. I would use the one that doesn't create the trailing comma since that matches rustfmt-formatted code for a single-line function call, but either one is easily understood.

Comment: Note that while as is there is no preferrence, when you add another argument after you must use `$($arg,)*`, because using `$($arg),* ,` will yield an error when no arguments are given.